# What symbols have represented Christianity through the years?

Tags: symbolism

Today the cross is the primary icon of Christianity, but I'm aware of a few others, such as the [Ichthys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichthys).  What symbols have represented the faith through the centuries?

Comment: seems rather listy. maybe ask the meaning behind the symbol?

Comment: @DForck42 Listy, but possibly useful, for identifying brothers.

Comment: maybe, but i can think of jsut a few off the top of my head.  the other question is, are you asking for symbols that generally represent christianity, or would symbols that represent a specific religion also work?  because a rosary is a strong catholic symbol, but it's not a general symbol of christianity.

Comment: I think this may not be the best place to ask questions like this: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Answer (score 3):

An anchor was used by the early christians as a symbol of faith. "as an anchor of the soul, sure and firm" (Hebrews 6:19-20). There are several variations some of them can be seen in [jesuswalk.com](http://www.jesuswalk.com/christian-symbols/anchor.htm)

Another very famous symbol is the chi and rho. Which was used by emperor Constantine as a heavenly divine symbol (coeleste signum dei) on the shields of his soldiers defeating Maxentius in the Battle of Milvian Bridge. For a depiction look at this brief [article of Rochester University](http://www.rochester.edu/college/rel/symbols/chiro.html). The chi and rho are also believed to be reference to the first letters of the word Christ.

Another beatiful symbol is the lamb of god, which makes reference to the imagery of the book of revelation. The meaning of this symbol is explained by John the Baptist himself. "Behold the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world" in John 1:29. I think the most beautiful of this depictions can be seen in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_of_God)

This list does not pretend to be exhaustive.